# Migrar sitio a local (XAMPP) - ERROR require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, xampp

Al parecer no logra llegar a la ruta indicada,
migré mi sitio de producción a XAMPP para trabajar en local.

el error es :

> `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:/xampp/htdocs/libreria/php/adodb5/adodb.inc.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\control_documental\clase\sistema\conexionLn.php on
>   line 24`

el código de conexionLn.php es:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == '127.0.0.1')
{
    $direccion_acceso_libreria_conexion = Archivo::extraerDireccionServer().'control_documental/';
}
else
{
    $direccion_acceso_libreria_conexion = Archivo::extraerDireccionServer();
}
```

> require_once($direccion_acceso_libreria_conexion.'libreria/php/adodb5/adodb.inc.php');

y desde donde obtengo la dirección:

```
public static function extraerDireccionServer()
{
    $direccion=str_replace('//', '/', ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/"));
    return $direccion;
}

public static function extraerDireccionWeb()
{
    $direccion = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    return $direccion;
}
```

Comment: Te fijaste que esa carpeta exista "C:/xampp/htdocs/libreria/php"

Comment: @JorgeEduardoAdan tienes razón, no me había fijado en ese detalle, y porque no me estará trayendo desde el proyecto? debiera ser:
`C:/xampp/htdocs/control_documental/libreria/php/adodb5/adodb.inc.php`

Comment: php 5.5 , sqlServer 2005 (conexion ok).

Comment: php plano, y apache.

Comment: si está entrando al if en conexionLn.php???

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69074/discussion-between-francisco-acevedo-and-jorge-eduardo-adan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al parecer en la clase conexionLn.php el parámetro $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] para obtener el localhost es diferente y debes cambiar la condición dentro del if para que te funcione correctamente.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost:8080')
{
    $direccion_acceso_libreria_conexion = Archivo::extraerDireccionServer().'control_documental/';
}
```

ahí se cambió el '127.0.0.1' por 'localhost:8080'

Comment: gracias amigo!!!